# SubSonic (2.1) ExecuteTypedList Performance Issue

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, subsonic

We are using SubSonic 2.1 to get information from our SQL database. I noticed that when we execute a stored procedure by means of a data set the information gets pulled back fairly quick. When we execute the store procedure by ExecuteTypedList it takes a good 20-30 seconds to pull the info. The stored procedure in stand alone takes 4-5 seconds every time. I have changed the call to the stored procedure so it does not use subsonic at all and it pulls the info back in the same 4-5 seconds. Is there any reason why subsonic would be causing an issue to pull back the info? The query itself is only returning 1 line of results.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I do know that `ExecuteTypedList` will use reflection to populate each .Net object it creates while materializing your record set.

If your record classes implement `IActiveRecord` or `IRecordBase` SubSonic will use this contract to populate each instance with data and it should be somewhat faster than the reflection based implementation.

But if your result set contains only one row, I suppose this likely isn't the issue.